# .htaccess rewrite rules to new domain name & path (retain file name)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-masking

This is our 1st attempt with .htaccess scription. Please help us with the below requirement:

Actual URL:
https://domaina.com/Criteria1/valueaddedcourse/2202223742-first aid course.pdf

If the URL Contains "/Criteria1/valueaddedcourse/" then it should redirect to a new domain & path but with same file name (2202223742-first aid course.pdf)

https://qaanr.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2202223742-first aid course.pdf

Being a newbie, find apache tutorial too cryptic (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html)

Please do share content with details description for .htaccess - this will help us to learn.

==== Update to above question ===

this code works for me:

`
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Criteria1/valueaddedcourse/
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://qaanr.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/% {REQUEST_FILENAME} [P]

`

this code works for redirection, **Fails to mask**. Browser has to show the original domain name & not https://qaanr.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Criteria1/valueaddedcourse/
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://qaanr.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [P]

this code works for redirection, Fails to mask. 

It has to display the original domain name & not https://qaanr.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Criteria1/valueaddedcourse/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://qaanr.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Usage = If the URL Contains "/Criteria1/valueaddedcourse/" then it will redirect to a new domain & path but with same file name (2202223742-first aid course.pdf)

Comment: This did not work. Error message:

<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>/home/anracin/domains/anr.ac.in/private_html/Criteria1</Key>
<RequestId>DVYW11DK0HTYHMP9</RequestId>
<HostId>W8En1R4vqbss4aUT/MXMB1IzyphgRM8e0YfWXKaN2RCJoWTK1Nc609KT1YmZAUa2ApFN33GRz5c=</HostId>
</Error>